# angular 5 populate form fields using other field values if checkbox is selected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-forms

I've got two sections of forms - correspondence address and residential address. The goal is to copy/pass values from one field to another if a checkbox is checked. Kindly see below use case

- populate the correspondence address fields with the values of the residential address form fields iff a checkbox (same as residential address) is checked
- Should any form field in the residential address change after checking the checkbox, pass the change(s) realtime to the field in the correspondence
  address and
- lastly, clear the form values in the correspondence address if the checkbox is unchecked. Below is what i've tried

> Component.ts

```
populateCorrespondenceAdd(event) {
    //console.log(event.checked)
    if (event.checked) {
        [...]
        this.correspondenceHouseNumber = 
        this.residentialHouseNumber;
        this.correspondenceStreetName = 
        this.enrollee.residentialStreetName;
        this.enrollee.correspondenceLGA = 
        this.enrollee.residentialLGA;
        [...]
    }
}
```

> component.html

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="populateCorrespondenceaddress" (change)="populateCorrespondenceAdd($event)"
                formControlName="populateCorrespondenceadd" value="true">Same as residential address?)</mat-checkbox>
```

The code above doesn't quite meet expectation as (i) unchecking the checkbox doesn't clear the form fields (ii) after checking the checkbox, if there's any change(s) in any of the form fields in the residential address section, the correspondence form fields doesn't update to reflect the changes.
**N:B: The fields are in one form group**

Kindly guide.

Comment: since it a reactive form, you could subscribe to form value changes and do the necessary  https://kfarst.github.io/angular/2016/12/12/subscribing-to-form-value-changes-in-angular-2/

Answer (score 2):

I've simplified a bit your example and used:
- sending address
- billing address

Otherwise I think it's pretty much the same :)

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface Address {
  street: string;
  city: string;
  country: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public isSameAddressControl: FormControl = new FormControl(false);

  public addresses: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    sendingAddress: this.fb.group({
      street: '',
      city: '',
      country: ''
    }),
    billingAddress: this.fb.group({
      street: '',
      city: '',
      country: ''
    })
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isSameAddressControl
      .valueChanges
      .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(isSameAddress => {
          if (isSameAddress) {
            return this.addresses
              .get('sendingAddress')
              .valueChanges
              .pipe(
                // at the beginning fill the form with the current values
                startWith(this.addresses.get('sendingAddress').value),
                tap(value =>
                  // every time the sending address changes, update the billing address 
                  this.addresses
                    .get('billingAddress')
                    .setValue(value)
                )
              )
          } else {
            this.addresses
              .get('billingAddress')
              .reset();

            return EMPTY;
          }
        })
        // don't forget to unsubscribe when component's destroyed
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" [formControl]="isSameAddressControl"> Same address for sending/billing

<form [formGroup]="addresses">
  <ng-container formGroupName="sendingAddress">
    Sending address<br>
    <input type="text" formControlName="street" placeholder="Street" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="text" formControlName="city" placeholder="City" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="text" formControlName="country" placeholder="Country" autocomplete="off"><br>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container formGroupName="billingAddress">
    Billing address<br>
    <input type="text" formControlName="street" placeholder="Street" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="text" formControlName="city" placeholder="City" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="text" formControlName="country" placeholder="Country" autocomplete="off"><br>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Here's a working example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nyjsnt

Comment: Thanks for your guide. How can i use this sample with rxjs 5.5.2. I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Instead of pipe you have to chain the calls for observables (but you should rather upgrade...)

Comment: Please can you kindly guide on how to use chain instead of pipe. Thank you

Comment: Wondering why somebody just down voted my answer. I'd be glad to get an explanation :)

Comment: Excellent answer! However I seem to be getting an error on the `switchMap(isSameAddress => { ...` line. 

Error: TS2345: Argument of type '(isSameAddress: any) => Observable<any> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.