# How to copy input field value when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form in which there is a `local` and a `permanent` field. I want to copy all local fields to the permanent field if the user checked the checkbox, or if the user unchecked the checkbox I need to blank all the permanent fields.

I tried this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypzjrk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
    cf: FormGroup;
    isChecked:boolean;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
  this.isChecked = false;
  this.cf = this.fb.group({
          district: [''],
           city: [''],
          permanentDistrict: [''],
          permanentCity: [''],

  })


}
checkValue(){
    alert(this.isChecked);
  }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504991/angular-5-populate-form-fields-using-other-field-values-if-checkbox-is-selected seems like this question has something similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created another sample example, without model value changes approach on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxweb-without-model-based-value-changes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Here is the code of component.

```js
 ngOnInit(){
    this.addressFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
          isSameAddress:[false],
          district: [''],
          city: [''],
          permanentDistrict: [''],
          permanentCity: [''],
    });
  }

  checked(value:boolean){
    if(value){
      this.addressFormGroup.controls.permanentDistrict.setValue(this.addressFormGroup.value.district);
      this.addressFormGroup.controls.permanentCity.setValue(this.addressFormGroup.value.city)
    }else{
      this.addressFormGroup.controls.permanentDistrict.setValue(undefined);
      this.addressFormGroup.controls.permanentCity.setValue(undefined)
    }
  }
```

Any confusion, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cannot use `ngModel` if you using it inside `formGroup`. Instead you should use `formControlName` and move `isChecked` in side the form group

Change this

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" class="" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="checkValue(isChecked)">
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" class="" formControlName="isChecked" (change)="checkValue(isChecked)">
```

and in your ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
    cf: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.cf = this.fb.group({
          district: [''],
           city: [''],
          permanentDistrict: [''],
          permanentCity: [''],
          isChecked: false

  })


}
checkValue(){
    console.log(this.cf.value.isChecked);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To show how to accomplish your aim , I forked a demo based on yours , please check it.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcp6ng

Answer (score 0):

However you could also use setValue(or in your case better use patchValue, to set the value of your fields if that is checked. using the valueChanges method will return an observable you can then patchValue if the user changes a value after the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a class for Address and map local and permanent address, then you can set values when checkbox is checked. And instantiate when checkbox is not checked.
[See example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unigvw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

A few changes in html due to use of ngModel and removing form elements.

```
interface address{
  district?,
  city?
}
class addressInfo implements address{
  constructor(
    public district?: string,
    public city?: string
) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  cf: FormGroup;
  isChecked:boolean;
  localAddress: address = new addressInfo();
  permanentAddress: address = new addressInfo();

  constructor(){
    this.isChecked = false;
  }
  checkValue(){
  //alert(this.isChecked);
     if(this.isChecked){
       this.permanentAddress = this.localAddress;
       console.log(this.permanentAddress);
     }
     else{
       this.permanentAddress = new addressInfo();
     }
    }

  }
```